# JPA does not delete database row

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm facing a delete problem with JPA, and this is my code:

```
public deleteLine(int idLine) {
  Line line = em.find(Line.class,idLine);
  Header header = line.getHeader();
  this.deleteLine(header,line);
}

public boolean deleteLine(Header header, Line line) {
    try {
      line.setIdArticle(null);
      line.setDetail(DELETED_TAG);
      line.setQuantity(0.0f);
      em.merge(line);
      header.getLineCollection().remove(line);
      em.remove(line);
      em.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  return true;
}
```

When I call `deleteLine()`, I end with a database row with `idArticle` being `null`, details equal to `DELETED_TAG` constant and `quantity` equal to `0`. But the row is still there, despite the `em.remove`.

I've tried to add a `line.setHeader(null)` before the removal, but I get a `ConstraintViolationException` because the header field cannot be `null`.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what.

There's entities code:

```
public class Header implements Serializable {
  [...]
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "header")
  private Collection<Line> lineCollection;
  [...]
}

public class Line implements Serializable {
  [...]
  @JoinColumn(name = "header", referencedColumnName = "header")
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Header header;
  [...]
}
```

I've done tests deleting the row via JPQL (`DELETE FROM Linea WHERE idLinea=?`), and it effectively deletes the row. But then, when JPA does the commit, the line reappears due to an `INSERT` done by JPA.

Is there a way to discover why? Obviously, there's an entity that generates the insert, but I'm removing the line form the header, so what can I do to figure out what is triggering the insert?

Comment: How try with removing the merged entity like `em.remove(em.merge(line));` ???

Comment: em.remove(em.merge(line)); is the same as doing em.merge(line); em.remove(line);

Comment: No, it isn't the same. merge() returns the attached entity. it leaves its argument detached.

Comment: @moretti.fabio You will get managed instance returned from `em.merge()` !!!

Comment: I've tried, getting same result. Anyway, the entites I pass to the function are attached because the line is the result of em.find and the header is line.getHeader(); I'm really wondering what happens, I can see the update query sent de database but the delete never happen

Comment: I've edited the code claryfing I'm getting managed entities, sorry for being not clear.

Comment: @moretti.fabio if it is sure that the passed `line` instance is managed one as under transaction bounty, you should check your entity relationship and cascading between them.

Comment: Why my question gets downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out where the problem was: when the user deletes a row, I was doing this

- call deleteLine
- do some calculations and update the header with the results

Due to how jpa works, the modifications to the header fields force jpa to skip deleting the child (because of the cascade all) or reinserting it, because in fact, the entity still exists and hibernate "walks" and reconstructs the parent-childs tree.

For people facing the same problem, the correct way I've found if you want to delete a child and update the parent after the deletion is:

- remove the child from the parent collection
- update the header
- delete the child

For me, doing thing in this exact order solved the problem.